# Why do I get a NullReferenceException in this foreach method

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

```
int count = 0;

foreach (string s in Settings.Default.Name)
{
    count++;
}

Settings.Default.Name[count] = tb_add_name.Text;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

`Settings.Default.Name` is an empty string array but should the foreach - method just dont start if the string array is empty instead of giving me this error?

The array will be filled with words later.

Comment: Settings.Default.Name and empty array so how foreach interate over it, it should throw NullRefferenceException

Comment: There are two possible causes for a `NullReferenceException` here: Either `Settings.Default.Name` is null (which would mean that it is *not* an empty string array), or `tb_add_name` is null. The error stack trace will tell you which of these it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but that won't change the fact that count is still 0 and you still execute 
`Settings.Default.Name[count] = tb_add_name.Text;`

So you should still check if the index is Valid or null. Something like:

```
if(Settings.Default.Name != null && Settings.Default.Name.Count > 0)
```

By the way, your method will always lead to an `IndexOutOfRange` exception because your foreach loop basically sets your `count` variable to the size of the Array, and `Array[Array.Length]` is always out of range.

Comment: You can iterate an empty enumerable, so there is nothing wrong with the count being zero. However, OP’s code will still fail because after the loop, `count` has the value `Settings.Default.Name.Count` (i.e. one more than the last index), and you can’t set values outside of the index range. You would need to actually `Add` an element (for which you don’t even need the index).

Comment: I tried the Code but "Settings.Default.Name.Count > 0" doesnt work
i get the error: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'

Comment: Oh and now i get the error NullReferenceException here: 'Settings.Default.Name[count] = tb_add_Name.Text'
But 'count' is 0 and 'tb_add_Name.Text' is not empty or null

Comment: Are you sure that `tb_add_Name` and Settings.Default are both not null?
If yes, what is the size of Settings.Default.Name when you execute that line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array `Length` property.

```
if(Settings.Default.Name.Count > 0)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach (string s in Settings.Default.Name)
    {
        count++;
    }

    Settings.Default.Name[count] = tb_add_name.Text;
    Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Comment: `Settings` has no `Length` property, and none of this will prevent the null reference exception that is apparently being thrown.

Comment: I updated my answer. I miss Count